# unable to filter() users with their date_joined field

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to count all the users whose date_joined matches with 'today's' date. I have two users who have today's date in the date_joined field but the count always returns zero. I am perhaps not filtering the data correctly. These are the waays that I have tried to filter the data

**models**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    email = models.EmailField( unique= True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank= True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank= True)
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank= True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank= True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views**

```
from datetime import datetime, date

def dashboard(request):

    all_users = CustomUser.objects.all().exclude(is_staff = True).count()

    all_users_bydate = CustomUser.objects.all().filter(date_joined= datetime.today()).count()

    print(all_users_bydate)
```

```
all_users_bydate = CustomUser.objects.all().filter(date_joined= datetime.today().date()).count()
```

```
all_users_bydate = CustomUser.objects.all().filter(date_joined= datetime.today().date()).count()
```

even tried to explicitly filter

```
all_users_bydate = CustomUser.objects.all().filter(date_joined= date(2021, 12, 11)).count()
```

all of these ways did not work at all and always retuned zero. Please rectify me what I am doing wrong.

[image: These are two users with today's date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with code for some time what I understood is all the ways that I have tried earlier where returning zero beaccuse 'date_joined" is a DateTimeField, therefore, in the code below

```
all_users_bydate = CustomUser.objects.all().filter(date_joined= datetime.today().date()).count()
```

the time is not getting matched hence, the count was being returned as 0.

So what I did is I used __contains to filter the date. So, this checks whether today's date is contained in the 'date_joined' field. This returns the correct count, i.e. 2.

```
 all_users_bydate = CustomUser.objects.all().filter(date_joined__contains= datetime.today().date()).count()
```